# Is it possible to force record type in F# when doing an assignment?

Tags: f#

To explain I think it is best with an example:

```
type myRec = {x: string}
type myRec2 = {x: string}
let x = {x = "hello"}
let y(a: myRec) = a.x
y(x);;

  y(x);;
   --^

error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    myRec    
but here has type
    myRec2
```

So how do I force `x` to have the type `myRec` if both `myRec` and `myRec2` has the same signature?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
let x = { myRec.x = "hello" }
// or
let x:myRec = { x = "hello" }
// or
let x = { x = "hello" } : myRec
```

Further details and examples are available in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184.aspx).

<sub>**EDIT:** Incorporated alternatives from comments.</sub>

Comment: I also found out that I could write: `let x:myRec = {x = "hello"}`, which I think is most readable one.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, let me add `let x = { x = "hello" } : myRec`.

Comment: @JohnReynolds, almost got a little bit of the old perl mantra going on here: "There's more than one way to do it." If it is good or not is to early for me to say.

Comment: @TomasJansson : As always, consistency is key. :-]

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can:

```
let x = { new myRec() with x = "hello" }
```

use `and` to assign more fields:

```
let x = { new myRec3() with x = "hello" and y = "bye" }
```

Comment: This causes an extra (unnecessary) allocation.